# Editing object inside an object in an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have the following two types:

```
export default interface ImageDataForAnnotation {
    src: string;
    name: string;
    key: number;
    regions?: Annotation[]; //This is defined below
    pixelSize?: PixelSize
}


export interface Annotation {
    type: string,
    x: number,
    y: number,
    w: number,
    h: number,
    highlighted: boolean,
    editingLabels: boolean,
    color: string,
    cls: string | undefined,
    id: number,
    image?: number,

}
```

Then i have an array where each image holds a number of annotations

```
  const [images, addImage] = useState<Array<ImageDataForAnnotation>>([]);
  
  //Definition of arary

  let imageArray = [...images];
```

I then want to edit an annotation in a given image, where i have both indexes to do something like: `imageArray[image_index].regions![annotation_index].update(new_annotation)`

Comment: What did you try till now and are you facing any issues or errors?

Comment: I tried pushing a new annotation for the image with: imageArray[index].regions!.push(new_annotation)
Which works, but then i am unable to delete the old one using: imageArray[index].regions!.splice(annotation_index,1)
Optimally i would like to do this in just one operation though.

Answer (score 0):

I would firstly rename the method as `addImage` is misleading because the method may be used to edit/update, or even remove/delete items from `images` array.

So, firstly:

```
 const [images, setImages] = useState<Array<ImageDataForAnnotation>>([]);
```

Next, let us assume the index are available at variables named: `imageIndex` and `annotationIndex` (again, *CamelCase* is my preference) and the value that needs to be used is at `newAnnotation`, then to update the corresponding item within the state-variable `images`, here's what I would do:

```
setImages(prev => {
  const curr = [...prev];
  curr?.[imageIndex]?.regions?.[annotationIndex] = newAnnotation;
  return curr;
});
```

Use the `callback` function to access the `previous-state` of `images` and then update the specific item and return the updated version. I've used a shallow-copy `curr` for better readability & it's not necessary.